# Avoid nested for loops using List Comprehension and/or map

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, optimization

For a couple of days I've been struggling with how to **optimize** (not only make it look nicer) the 3 *nested loops* containing a *conditional* and a *function call* inside. What I have right now is the following:

```
def build_prolongation_operator(p,qs):
    '''
    p: dimension of the coarse basis
    q: dimension of the fine basis

    The prolongation operator describes the relationship between
    the coarse and fine bases:    
    V_coarse = np.dot(V_fine, I)
    '''

    q = sum(qs)

    I = np.zeros([q, p])

    for i in range(0, q):
        for j in range(0, p):
            for k in range(0, qs[j]):
                # if BV i is a child of j, we set I[i, j] = 1
                if i == f_map(j, k, qs):
                    I[i, j] = 1
                    break

    return I
```

where `f_map` is:

```
def f_map(i, j, q):
    '''
    Mapping which returns the index k of the fine basis vector which
    corresponds to the jth child of the ith coarse basis vector.    
    '''

    if j < 0 or j > q[i]:
        print('ERROR in f_map')
        return None

    result = j

    for k in range(0, i):
        result += q[k]

    return result
```

When profiling my whole code I get that `build_prolongation_operator` is called 45 times and `f_map` approximately **8.5 million times!!**

Here is the picture:

[image: picture]

I have tried to do the same with list comprehension and a map, but without any luck.

Here is a sample of the inputs that `build_prolongation_operator` expects:

```
p = 10
qs = randint(3, size=p)
```

Comment: List comprehensions or  ``map`` will *still* perform your operation 8.5 million times. The performance differences between these constructs is negligible for any non-trivial code such as yours. If you provide more context (e.g. what ``qs`` is) it may be possible to design a better algorithm. Consider also looking into numpy's builtin vectorisation features, or possibly Cython for a brute-force optimisation.

Comment: You might be able to replace the three loops with vector multiplications. What is `p`, `qs` and what do you expect `I` to be?

Comment: I think one of your loops is not necessary at all. The outer one specifically. Please provide a *sample* input so we can *play* with it.

Comment: @Mad, that would be supremely better than the memoization I proposed :-)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for your time. for testing this i made {qs = np.random.randint(3, size(p))} being p only an integer.

Comment: @Jonas Thanks for taking the time to respond. `p` is an integer (i.e the number of columns of I), `qs = np.random.randint(3, size = p)` just an array of length p with random integers. What I expect to have is a matrix `I` of dimension `q x p` full of zeros and ones depending on the conditional

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks. You can see in my above comment the input to my function. Take `p` to be, lets say, 100, and `qs = np.random.randint(3, size(p))`

Comment: General optimizing remarks: First, calling a function in Python comes with some overhead. If this is really something you need to optimize, you can optimize it by inlining the function. Second, a list comprehension is still a loop, it just looks nicer. Third, the map built-in of Python is faster if the function in it, is a built-in, or at least something in C instead of Python. This is caused by the fact that the function call overhead is larger than the loop overhead. Last, a nested loop is often faster than using a map with a tuple, because tuple packing and unpacking is overhead as well.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga Thanks for the remark. I will take it in consideration

Comment: @GuillermoAlejandroBarrazaMo. I figured out how to turn this into basically a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you really don't need `p` as a parameter to your function: `len(qs)` only needs to be called once, and it's extremely cheap. If your input is always a numpy array (and under the circumstances there is no reason it shouldn't be), `qs.size` will do as well.

Let's start by rewriting `f_map`. The loop there is just the cumulative sum of `qs` (but starting with zero), which you can pre-compute once (or at least once per call to the outer function).

```
def f_map(i, j, cumsum_q):
    return j + cumsum_q[i]
```

Where `cumsum_q` would be defined in `build_prolongation_operator` as

```
cumsum_q = np.roll(np.cumsum(qs), 1)
cumsum_q[0] = 0
```

I am sure you could appreciate the usefulness of having the same set of variable names inside `f_map` as you have in `build_prolongation_operator`. To make it even easier, we can just remove `f_map` entirely and use the expression it represents instead in your condition:

```
if i == k + cumsum_q[j]:
    I[i, j] = 1
```

The loop over `k` then means "if `i` is `k + cumsum[j]` for *any* `k`", set the element to 1. If we rewrite the condition as `i - cumsum_q[j] == k`, you can see that we don't need a loop over `k` at all. `i - cumsum_q[j]` will be equal to *some* `k` in the range `[0, qs[j])` if it is non-negative and strictly less than `qs[j]`. You can just check

```
if i >= cumsum_q[j] and i - cumsum_q[j] < qs[j]:
    I[i, j] = 1
```

This reduces your loop to one iteration per element of the matrix. You can't do better than that:

```
def build_prolongation_operator_optimized(qs):
    '''
    The prolongation operator describes the relationship between
    the coarse and fine bases:    
    V_coarse = np.dot(V_fine, I)
    '''
    qs = np.asanyarray(qs)
    p = qs.size
    cumsum_q = np.roll(np.cumsum(qs), 1)
    q = cumsum_q[0]
    cumsum_q[0] = 0

    I = np.zeros([q, p])

    for i in range(0, q):
        for j in range(0, p):
            # if BV i is a child of j, we set I[i, j] = 1
            if 0 <= i - cumsum_q[j] < qs[j]:
                I[i, j] = 1
    return I
```

Now that you now that you know the formula for each cell, you can have numpy compute the whole matrix for you in essentially one line using broadcasting:

```
def build_prolongation_operator_numpy(qs):
    qs = np.asanyarray(qs)
    cumsum_q = np.roll(np.cumsum(qs), 1)
    q = cumsum_q[0]
    cumsum_q[0] = 0
    i_ = np.arange(q).reshape(-1, 1)  # Make this a column vector
    return (i_ >= cumsum_q) & (i_ - cumsum_q < qs)
```

I ran a small demo to ensure that (A) The proposed solutions get the same result as your original, and (B) work faster:

```
In [1]: p = 10
In [2]: q = np.random.randint(3, size=p)

In [3]: ops = (
...     build_prolongation_operator(p, qs),
...     build_prolongation_operator_optimized(qs),
...     build_prolongation_operator_numpy(qs),
...     build_prolongation_operator_RaunaqJain(p, qs),
...     build_prolongation_operator_gboffi(p, qs),
... )

In [4]: np.array([[(op1 == op2).all() for op1 in ops] for op2 in ops])
Out[4]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]])

In [5]: %timeit build_prolongation_operator(p, qs)
321 µs ± 890 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [6]: %timeit build_prolongation_operator_optimized(qs)
75.1 µs ± 1.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [7]: %timeit build_prolongation_operator_numpy(qs)
24.8 µs ± 77.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [8]: %timeit build_prolongation_operator_RaunaqJain(p, qs)
28.5 µs ± 1.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [9]: %timeit build_prolongation_operator_gboffi(p, qs)
31.8 µs ± 772 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [10]: %timeit build_prolongation_operator_gboffi2(p, qs)
26.6 µs ± 768 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As you can see, the fastest option is the fully vectorized one, but [@RaunaqJain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52312431/2988730) and [@gboffi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314863/2988730) options come a very close second.

**Note**

My vectorized solution creates a boolean array. If you don't want that either use `I.astype(...)` to convert to the desired dtype, or view it as a `np.uint8` array: `I.view(dtype=np.uint8)`.

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed that `gboffi1` comes out slower than `RaunaqJain`, I have to ponder about my _"Calling a built-in should be more efficient than a function call and a loop, shouldn't it?"_ for a while...

Comment: Thank you for your time @Mad, the benchmark was really helpfull!

Answer (score 3):

I dunno about bases and prolongation operators, but you should focus on the algorithm itself. This is almost always sound advice where optimisation is concerned.

Here's probably the crux -- and if not, it's something to get you started: The `f_map` computation does not depend on `i`, but you are recomputing it for each value of `i`. Since `i` ranges from zero to the sum of the values in `qs`, you'll save a ginormous amount of recomputation by caching the results; google "python memoize" and it'll practically write itself. Fix this and you are probably done, without any micro-optimizations.

You'll need enough space to store `max(p) * max(qs[j])` values, but from the number of calls you report, this should not be much of an obstactle.

Comment: I don't think you even need memoization. You probably just need to get rid of the outer loop entirely and order the remaining two loops correctly with respect to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Try and check if this works,

```
for j in range(0,p):
    for k in range(0, qs[j]):
        # if BV i is a child of j, we set I[i,j] = 1
        val = f_map(j,k,qs)
        if I[val, j] == 0:
            I[val, j] = 1
```

Comment: Man!! this helped a lot! reduces the function call drastically! Thanks!!
I will just try some other approach, but this is a good solution!

Comment: I just made it more efficient, check that too.

Comment: You should break from both loops once you set a 1, not continue checking.

Comment: @Mad, from what I can understand from his function is that he is setting 1 whenever f_map returns a value equal to `i` and that too greedily (i.e. the first time as he breaks as soon as he finds it). Thus, if f_map returns 2, he needs to set `I[2, j] = 1`.  Correct me if my logic seems wrong.

Comment: @RaunaqJain This does the job. The difference in time is relatively small to the previous solution, and being better in ridding out of 1 function call

Comment: @RaunaqJain. I've posted what I think is the optimal logic

Comment: I've timed it, and your for loop is only a tiny fraction slower than a fully vectorized solution. Excellent work :)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even look at the f_map function since most of the time was going away in calling f_map and the outer loop. Your answer is great and from it what I am taking away is that I should always look at everything. I always fail in doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is the optimized loop as proposed by [Raunaq Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6087502/raunaq-jain) in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52312431/2749397)

```
for j in range(0,p):
    for k in range(0, qs[j]):
        # if BV i is a child of j, we set I[i,j] = 1
            val = f_map(j,k,qs)
            if I[val, j] == 0:
                I[val, j] = 1
```

and here it is the `f_map` function, where I have edited the names of the arguments to reflect the names used by the caller

```
def f_map(j,k,qs):
    if k < 0 or k > qs[j]:
        print('ERROR in f_map')
        return None
    result = k
    for i in range(0, j):
        result += qs[i]
    return result
```

We start by noting that it's always `0 ≤ k < qs[j]`, because of the definition of the loop on `k`, so that we can *safely* remove the sanity check and write

```
def f_map(j,k,qs):
    result = k
    for i in range(0, j):
        result += q[i]
    return result
```

Now, this is the doc string of the `sum` builtin

> Signature: sum(iterable, start=0, /)
>   Docstring:
>   Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers
>
> When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
>   This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may reject non-numeric types.
>   Type:      builtin_function_or_method

It is apparent that we can write

```
def f_map(j,k,qs):
    return sum(qs[:j], k)
```

and it is apparent also that we can do w/o the function call

```
for j in range(0,p):
    for k in range(0, qs[j]):
        # if BV i is a child of j, we set I[i,j] = 1
            val = sum(qs[:j], k)
            if I[val, j] == 0:
                I[val, j] = 1
```

Calling a built-in should be more efficient than a function call and a loop, shouldn't it?

---

*Addressing Mad Physicist's remark*

We can precompute the partial sums of `qs` to get a further speed-up

```
sqs = [sum(qs[:i]) for i in range(len(qs))] # there are faster ways...
...
for j in range(0,p):
    for k in range(0, qs[j]):
        # if BV i is a child of j, we set I[i,j] = 1
            val = k+sqs[j]
            if I[val, j] == 0:
                I[val, j] = 1
```

Comment: As my answer shows, you can optimize this much further by not computing the sum more than once.

Comment: Looks like your close parens key is stuck :)

Comment: I hope that you don't mind me fixing that as well as your summation limit.

Comment: The update makes a huge difference. I added a benchmark for that too.